# Kotlin - Difference between "forEachIndexed" and "for in" loop

Tags: for-loop, foreach, kotlin

I am confused on what are the advantages/disadvantages of each of these approaches (assuming I need to use both `index` and `product`):

```
products.forEachIndexed{ index, product ->
    ...
}

for ((index, product) in products.withIndex()) {
    ...
}
```

`products` here is a simple collection.

Is there any performance/best practice/etc argument to prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 12):

No, they are the same. You can read the source of [forEachIndexed](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/8cb194c03fa2a26889afafea6bf730528875b196/libraries/stdlib/src/generated/_Collections.kt#L1487) and [withIndex](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/caa2d7a6ce80901f240227ecd4819713c064a2a8/libraries/stdlib/src/generated/_Collections.kt#L1293).

```
public inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.forEachIndexed(action: (index: Int, T) -> Unit): Unit {
    var index = 0
    for (item in this) action(index++, item)
}


public fun <T> Iterable<T>.withIndex(): Iterable<IndexedValue<T>> {
    return IndexingIterable { iterator() }
}
```

`forEachIndexed` use a local var to count the index while `withIndex` create a decorator for iterator which also use a var to count index. In theory, `withIndex` create one more layer of wrapping but the performance should be the same.

Comment: `IndexedValue` is a data class. Performance will definitely not be similar (at least not for larger collections), because this will allocate not just one more object, but 1+iterable.size objects. Plus additional method call on the Iterable interface for each item (hasNext+next), while just one call for action in your first example. CPU-wise the performance may be similar, but not definitely not memory-wise. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: EDIT: I thought Kotlin optimized the IndexedValue temporary object away, but it was just a brainfart. It was hidden behind the `next()` call. Nevermind. My previous comment still stands.